# How to calculate and change a specific value inside my localstorage js

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, local-storage

I have a code where i am able to **add, display and delete** objects in ***local storage*** and its working but whenever i try to update a particular object, it instead overrides everything instead of just changing the particular one i want

**MY CODE**

```
$(".qty-val-ls").on("change", function() {
    let record = localStorage.getItem("guestCart");
    let index = $(this).attr("id");
    if(record == null)
    {
        recordObj = [];
    }else{
        recordObj = JSON.parse(record);
    }
    recordObj[index].price = $(this).val() * parseInt(recordObj[index].price);
    
    localStorage.setItem('guestCart', recordObj[index].price); 
})
```

**MY INPUT**

```
 <input type="number" class="qty-val-ls" min="1" id="${index}" value="4000" onChange="">
```

The **${index}** here is the id that is in the localstorage and the **index** in the jquery is the number where the object is like at in the localstorage, it starts from ***0, 1, 2 etc***

**MY ARRAY(OBJECT IN LOCALSTORAGE)**

```
[{"id":"11","name":"Rts 512GB USB Flash Drive Pendrive Memory USB 3.0","price":"3000","img":"newusb.png","qty":1},
{"id":"10","name":"MP3 Music Player Audio Player -Black","price":"5000","img":"mp3.png","qty":1},
{"id":"5","name":"Blue Louis Vuitton Women Bag","price":"10000","img":"newbag.png","qty":1},
{"id":"1","name":"Samsung Galaxy S9 6gb ram, 32gb rom, 16mpbs","price":"100000","img":"newphone.png","qty":1}]
```

So please how do i change the value after calculating and be able to put it back to where its supposed to be

EDIT: I have checked other similar questions on stackoverflow but none seems to work

Comment: ``Do localStorage.setItem('guestCart', recordOb); `` instead of ``localStorage.setItem('guestCart', recordObj[index].price);``

Comment: Also be careful with the line where you set the price value because `recordObj[index].price = ...` will throw an error when you initiate `recordObj` as an empty array

Comment: @Ravi it returns [object Object]:"[object Object]"

Comment: @VirgilioGM So how do i set it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to explain what was also said in the comments and give a good approach. First of all, you were overriding the stored object in localStorage with `recordObj[index].price` instead of the full `recordObj`. But, as you stated, storing `recordObj` and then getting its value gives `"[object Object]"` because it is parsed to string. Taking into account what I said about being careful when accessing to an items property because it could not exist yet, this code should work for you:

```js
$('.qty-val-ls').on('change', function onChange() {
    const record = localStorage.getItem('guestCart');
    const recordObj = record ? JSON.parse(record) : [];
    const index = $(this).attr('id');
    if (recordObj[index]) {
        recordObj[index].price = $(this).val() * parseInt(recordObj[index].price, 10);
    }
    localStorage.setItem('guestCart', JSON.stringify(recordObj)); 
});
```

Explaining what I did in more detail:

1. Get the localStorage item.
2. Parse it with `JSON.parse` if exists because it is stringified; if it doesn't exist, initialize it as an empty array.
3. If exists an item at the given index, set the price as you wanted. I also added the radix parameter to `parseInt` as it is a good practice and I'm used to follow that ESLint rule (https://eslint.org/docs/rules/radix)
4. Finally, store the modified (or not) and stringified array.

Comment: In const recordObj guestCart Isn't defined since it a key in local storage

Comment: so i changed the guestCart to record and it worked thank you very much

Comment: That's it, sorry, it was a mistake. I edited the answer to fix it